# Wrap existing SVG elements in G tag

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

This seems like it'd be a simple question to answer but I'm having a hard time doing so: Is it possible to "wrap" existing SVG shapes in a new SVG g tag (i.e. group) using d3.js, the way `.wrap()` works in jQuery? If I were to simply create a new g tag "manually", how would I then go about moving an existing element into that g?

Comment: D3 doesn't provide any functionality for that, it's much easier to use `wrap()` if that does what you're looking for.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff And jQuery does okay with wrapping elements in an SVG?

Comment: I've never used it myself, but I don't see why it shouldn't -- it's just a DOM as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you pass an existing DOM element to `append` or `insert`, the element (and it's children) will be moved from their current place in the DOM hierarchy to wherever you've just inserted them.

```
var stuffToBeWrapped = d3.selectAll(".stuff");

stuffToBeWrapped.each(function() {

   d3.select( this.parentNode ).insert("g", function(){return this;} ) 
              //insert a new <g> element immediately before this element
     .attr("class", "wrapper") //set anything you want to on the <g>
     .append( function(){return this;} );
             //move the content element into the group

});
```

It's a little messy because d3 expects you to always use functions to determine which element to insert or insert before, and that's not necessary when we're doing it all within an `each` statement.  But it should get the job done!

(Or, use the JQuery method if you've already got the library on your page.  JQuery doesn't usually have any problem *manipulating* SVG elements, it just can't create them!)

Answer (score 5):

Unable to make @AmeliaBR 's answer to work, I solved the problem like so

```
d3.selectAll(selectElementsToWrap).each(function() {
    var el = this;
    d3.select(el.parentNode)
      .insert("g")
      .attr("class", "wrapped")
      .append(function() { return el; });
});
```

The approved solution gave me `DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent`

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution is working for me. Probably the `this` binding is different when used inside the `append`.  Just one side note: you can replace the function declaration inside the  `append` function with a more compact arrow function. Something like `.append( () => el );`